# Do Regenerate and/or Totem Armor counteract the Legend rule?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-legendary-cards

Can a regeneration shield or a totem armor aura protect a Legendary creature from getting killed by a clone of itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. Regeneration and Totem Armor replace the "destroy" action, and the Legend Rule does not destroy.

---

> 704.5k If two or more legendary permanents with the same name are on the battlefield, all are **put into their owners’ graveyards**. This is called the “legend rule.” If only one of those permanents is legendary, this rule doesn’t apply.
>
> 701.12a If the effect of a resolving spell or ability regenerates a permanent, it creates a replacement effect that protects the permanent the next time it would be destroyed this turn. In this case, “Regenerate [permanent]” means “The next time [permanent] **would be destroyed** this turn, instead remove all damage marked on it and tap it. If it’s an attacking or blocking creature, remove it from combat.”
>
> 702.87a Totem armor is a static ability that appears on some Auras. “Totem armor” means “If enchanted permanent **would be destroyed**, instead remove all damage marked on it and destroy this Aura.”
>
> 701.6b The only ways a permanent can be destroyed are as a result of an effect that uses the word “destroy” or as a result of the state-based actions that check for lethal damage (see rule 704.5g) or damage from a source with deathtouch (see rule 704.5h). **If a permanent is put into its owner’s graveyard for any other reason, it hasn’t been “destroyed.”**